# Solr fails to load cores

Tags: solr, lucidworks

I added a misconfigured dynamic field to a Solr Core. Since, I cannot update anything to fix this error because Solr fails to load it.

The erroneous query:

```
http://solr.dev.fr:8983/solr/zCollection/schema
{
  "add-dynamic-field":{
     "name":"*_alz*",
     "type":"customFieldType",
     "stored":true,
     "indexed":true

}
```

The Exception :

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core zCollection_shard1_replica1: Can't load schema managed-schema: Dynamic field name '*_alz*' should have either a leading or a trailing asterisk, and no others.
```

The problem:

I can't find this dynamic field anywhere because I'm using `data_driven_schema_configs`

I can't use schema API to delete it; I get `404 Not Found` in response.

The Question:

Where can I found this element and delete it?

PS: I did a

```
grep -rnw '/opt/lucidworks-hdpsearch/' -e '_alz'
```

But nothing comes out with me.

---

Update 1 : 
I found the field in Zookeeper files  using:

```
./zkcli.sh -zkhost hmaster.dev.fr:2181 -cmd list
```

I downloaded the file

```
./zkcli.sh -zkhost hmaster.dev.fr:2181 -cmd get /configs/zCollection/managed-schema
```

Fixed the erroneous fields and uploaded it to ZK again:

```
./zkcli.sh -zkhost hmaster.dev.fr:2181 -cmd putfile /configs/zCollection/managed-schema managed-schema
```

And it works finally!!